# Chrome Driver tells that supports 114 version but it should support the 113 one - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))


driver.get(input("Link: "))
```

I've opened my app after some months and Chromium updated version. It's tells that ChromeDriver supports only 114 version, but I've installed the 113.0.5672.63 one but it's doesn't work like before.
When I try to start my Selenium app I get this error:

```
     
[29728:29416:0809/171603.204:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52567/devtools/browser/abc399bf-e2a2-40b8-8c14-360ebee67372
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 290, in start_session      
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response  
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114        
Current browser version is 113.0.5672.0 with binary path 
AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0078A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0071C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00625358]
        (No symbol) [0x006461AC]
        (No symbol) [0x00641EF3]
        (No symbol) [0x00640579]
        (No symbol) [0x00670C55]
        (No symbol) [0x0067093C]
        (No symbol) [0x0066A536]
        (No symbol) [0x006482DC]
        (No symbol) [0x006493DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009EAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A2A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A2456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008151E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x00725F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00722328]
        (No symbol) [0x0072240B]
        (No symbol) [0x00714FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75B07D59+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7728B79B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x7728B71F+191]
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: As completely different solution, you may want to use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) instead, which doesn't use webdriver but just talks directly to Chrome using the far more modern debugger api. Selenium will feel ridiculously overcomplicated once you're free of the whole webdriver nonsense.

Comment: @Gugu72 that question isn't even a question, and this question was asked first.

Comment: @UpAndAdam You're right, I should have asked for a merge since this might be the best asked question and the best answer is on the one I linked (downgrading the browser isn't a viable solution, nor downloading the last chrome driver manually, since you would need to not stay up-to-date, or to download the driver for each browser update)

Comment: The problem is the same, there _is_ a question on the target question, and date is not the most important thing for determining duplicate closure order. The target is far more visible at 17 _thousand_ views to this posts' mere 183. The solutions on the target are also the same, if not _more_ varied.

Comment: Good point @TylerH, i should have checked on meta what the way to handle that is, now i know.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of `selenium`, there's a driver manager that replaces `ChromeDriverManager`. You should no longer use `ChromeDriverManager` or pass in an `executable_path` to `Chrome()`.

Try this after upgrading your `selenium` version:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your webdriver to match your browser version

````
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager("113.0.5672.63").install())```
````

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114        
Current browser version is 113.0.5672.0 with binary path 
AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that *SessionNotCreatedException* was raised due to [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version mismatch.

---

### Details

The *Google Chrome* instance which you used to open your app is installed in a customized location, for which Chromium updated the version to ***v114.0***

However the *Google Chrome* instance which is installed at the default location i.e. `AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe` is still at ***113.0.5672.0***. Hence the mismatch.

---

### Solution

Manually open a *Google Chrome* instance using `AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe` binary and update the version and then execute your test. You'll be good to go.